# Aggregate data frame on date intervals

Tags: r

I have big data frame, for which a minimal working example is

```
df <- structure(list(
  from = structure(
    c(13858, 13859, 13860, 13861, 
      13864, 13865, 13866, 13867, 13868, 13871, 13871, 13872, 13873, 
      13874, 13875, 13878, 13878, 13879, 13880, 13881, 13882, 13885, 
      13886, 13887), class = "Date"), 
  to = structure(
    c(13859, 13860, 
      13861, 13864, 13865, 13866, 13867, 13868, 13871, 13872, 13874, 
      13873, 13874, 13875, 13878, 13879, 13880, 13880, 13881, 13882, 
      13885, 13886, 13887, 13888), class = "Date"), 
  X1 = c(6, 5, 5, NA, NA, 4, 5, 4, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6, 0, NA, NA, NA, 3, 
         5, 4, 5, 6, 10), 
  X2 = c(11, 5, 3, NA, 6, 10, 7, 3, 8, NA, 3, NA, NA, 7, 7, NA, 5, NA, 7, 
         4, 3, 2, 8, 8), 
  X3 = c(9, 3, 3, NA, 5, 7, 7, 6, 9, NA, 1, NA, NA, 6, 6, NA, 8, NA, 9, 2, 
         9, 4, 5, 9), 
  X4 = c(8, 5, 5, 4, 8, 8, 6, 5, 2, 4, NA, 10, 4, 4, 4, 5, NA, 4, 3, 3, 7, 
         3, 2, 1)), 
  .Names = c("from", "to", "X1", "X2", "X3", "X4"), 
  row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = "data.frame")
```

which looks like this

```
         from         to X1 X2 X3 X4
1  2007-12-11 2007-12-12  6 11  9  8
2  2007-12-12 2007-12-13  5  5  3  5
3  2007-12-13 2007-12-14  5  3  3  5
4  2007-12-14 2007-12-17 NA NA NA  4
5  2007-12-17 2007-12-18 NA  6  5  8
6  2007-12-18 2007-12-19  4 10  7  8
7  2007-12-19 2007-12-20  5  7  7  6
8  2007-12-20 2007-12-21  4  3  6  5
9  2007-12-21 2007-12-24  3  8  9  2
10 2007-12-24 2007-12-25 NA NA NA  4
11 2007-12-24 2007-12-27 NA  3  1 NA
12 2007-12-25 2007-12-26 NA NA NA 10
13 2007-12-26 2007-12-27 NA NA NA  4
14 2007-12-27 2007-12-28  6  7  6  4
15 2007-12-28 2007-12-31  0  7  6  4
16 2007-12-31 2008-01-01 NA NA NA  5
17 2007-12-31 2008-01-02 NA  5  8 NA
18 2008-01-01 2008-01-02 NA NA NA  4
19 2008-01-02 2008-01-03  3  7  9  3
20 2008-01-03 2008-01-04  5  4  2  3
21 2008-01-04 2008-01-07  4  3  9  7
22 2008-01-07 2008-01-08  5  2  4  3
23 2008-01-08 2008-01-09  6  8  5  2
24 2008-01-09 2008-01-10 10  8  9  1
```

The data frame is uniquely indexed by columns `from` and `to` jointly, because

```
anyDuplicated(df[c('from','to')])==0 # TRUE
```

but there are some duplicates in the sense that the (`from`,`to`) intervals don't uniquely partition the date range, i.e.

```
anyDuplicated(df['from'])>0 # TRUE
anyDuplicated(df['to'])>0 # TRUE
```

For example, the (`from`,`to`) interval between 24 Dec. 2007 and 27 Dec. 2007 also appears in the form of the three sub-intervals (24 Dec. 2007, 25 Dec. 2007), (25 Dec. 2007, 26 Dec. 2007) and (26 Dec. 2007, 27 Dec. 2007).

I would like to aggregate this data frame so that none of the date intervals in (`from`,`to`) overlap one another. I would like to sum the values in each of the data columns `X1`, ..., `X4` that are 'duplicated' in this sense. The resulting data frame should look like this

```
         from         to X1 X2 X3 X4
1  2007-12-11 2007-12-12  6 11  9  8
2  2007-12-12 2007-12-13  5  5  3  5
3  2007-12-13 2007-12-14  5  3  3  5
4  2007-12-14 2007-12-17 NA NA NA  4
5  2007-12-17 2007-12-18 NA  6  5  8
6  2007-12-18 2007-12-19  4 10  7  8
7  2007-12-19 2007-12-20  5  7  7  6
8  2007-12-20 2007-12-21  4  3  6  5
9  2007-12-21 2007-12-24  3  8  9  2
10 2007-12-24 2007-12-27 NA  3  1 18
11 2007-12-27 2007-12-28  6  7  6  4
12 2007-12-28 2007-12-31  0  7  6  4
13 2007-12-31 2008-01-02 NA  5  8  9
14 2008-01-02 2008-01-03  3  7  9  3
15 2008-01-03 2008-01-04  5  4  2  3
16 2008-01-04 2008-01-07  4  3  9  7
17 2008-01-07 2008-01-08  5  2  4  3
18 2008-01-08 2008-01-09  6  8  5  2
19 2008-01-09 2008-01-10 10  8  9  1
```

I haven't encountered a problem like this before and I wasn't able to find a similar question on stackoverflow. This seems like a more complex type of aggregation than I am used to doing with `aggregate()`. So any solutions, code or references would be appreciated.